# How to change sequence using SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to change some data in a table with `_id_seq` suffix with this sql query:

```
UPDATE user_custom_fields_id_seq SET last_value = 1000;
```

but I get the following error:

`ERROR:  cannot change sequence "user_custom_fields_id_seq"`

Is there anyway to bypass this error by using just SQL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [ATER SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-altersequence.html) command:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE user_custom_fields_id_seq
    RESTART WITH 1000;
```

`user_custom_fields_id_seq` is not a table, it is a sequence.

Comment: Or use `setval()`